# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when calling getDrawable()

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-drawable

I get the following out of memory error and I'm not sure why.

```
Failed to allocate a 1860508 byte allocation with 905740 free bytes and 884KB until OOM

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1860508 byte allocation with 905740 free bytes and 884KB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) 
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:837)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:656) 
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1037) 

at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4056) 
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929) 
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1991) 
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1973) 
at android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable.inflate(LevelListDrawable.java:128) 
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1192) 
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1086) 
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4045) 
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929) 
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1991) 
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1973) 
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:409)
at com.MyCompany.MyApp.Login.updateWifiStatus(Login.java:942)
at com.MyCompany.MyApp.Login$6.run(Login.java:576) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I am using a 5 level resource to indicate wifi status and here is the code I'm using

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    // Level of current connection
    int rssi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 5);
    Drawable db = getDrawable(R.drawable.stat_sys_wifi_signal);
    db.setLevel(level);
    wifiMenu.setIcon(db);
```

The images are all the same size (512x512).

In reference to other answers out there I have got largeheap in my manifest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is size if your image in KBs?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: biggest one is 32kb

Comment: read the link mentioned link. and pass the Bitmap Options accordingly

Comment: I've read the link but as I'm using a drawable with levels how do I scale down the image? I can see how it works with r.drawable.image for example but for levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/)

> TinyPNG uses smart lossy compression techniques to reduce the file
>   size of your PNG files. By selectively decreasing the number of colors
>   in the image, fewer bytes are required to store the data. The effect
>   is nearly invisible but it makes a very large difference in file size!

Compress all images using this link.

Reduce the size of all picture before use in your Android applications.

Make sure you read the document [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) given by @mudit_sen.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link to TinyPNG, saved over 50% in size. I've read the link but as I'm using a drawable with levels how do I scale down the image? I can see how it works with r.drawable.image for example but for levels?

Comment: Try moving your drawables from lower MPI to HDPI or  XHDPI depending on your resolution.

Comment: Move the 5 wifi icons into those folders e.g. mipmap-hdpi? What will that do?

Comment: Best practice is to add images to all drawable folder. But at that time to just try to move your images in higher resolution folder. Because, If you add all images in only one mdpi folder than system scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down for low-density screens, as appropriate.

Comment: Use this link for more reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

Comment: Ok great, I'll give that a go. Just wondering with the Out of memory error why it would error on some but not all devices? especially if its the same make and model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158992/discussion-between-mitesh-vanaliya-and-slideruk).